# PySpark - Precalculating Samples

Tags: python, pyspark, persistence

I am working with a big dataframe in PySpark. I want to calculate the mode of every column and decided that to speed it up to grab the mode of a sample of the dataframe instead. My initial attempt didn't work as expected and the calculations still took a very long time. I thought this might have something to do with something I read ages ago about how Spark doesn't do any "precalculations". I did some googling and it seems like what I wanted to do was mark my dataframe as persistent. This worked to some extent but the algorithm is still very slow.

As of now taking the sample takes approximately 2 s whilst calculating the mode of every column takes around 1 s For a sample size of 1000 rows this seems like way too long.

Can someone explain where my reasoning is incorrect here? I am not very familiar with Spark so basic level would be great.

Thanks

```
def remove_overwhelming_mode(df, cutoff=0.95, sample_n=None):
  
    num_rows = df.count()
  
    df_sampled = df
    df_sampled.persist()
    if sample_n is not None:
      df_sampled = df.sample(sample_n / num_rows, seed=seed)
  
    
    cutoff *= num_rows
    drop_cols = []
  
    columns = df.columns
    for col in columns:
      if df_sampled.groupby(col).count().orderBy("count", ascending=False).first()[1] > cutoff:
        drop_cols.append(col)
    
    return df.drop(*drop_cols)
```

EDIT:

This is called on any generic PySpark dataframe, `df`, like so:

```
df = remove_overwhelming_mode(df, sample_n=100)
```

and would then return `df` where all columns where the mode of the sample is in more than 95 % of entries in the same sample have been removed.

Comment: maybe you can provide a sample input/output (or you can create some artificial inputs) so that I know what exactly you want to achieve and I can code accordingly.

Comment: @XYZ Yes, see edit.

Comment: Hi Ivar, it is best you can create some artificial inputs.  The nature of the speed depends on how your input data is stored. If every columns information is independent with each other, it is best to read the input as column-oriented data file instead of row-oriented data file.    
For the row-oriented data file, when calculating the mode of one column (e.g. the 5th column), it actually needs to read all the rows data, and find 5th element of that row, and aggregate the 5th element of each row into one column and do the subsequent calculation.

Comment: if you read your input as column-oriented data file, then the code can read the first column, find the mode, ..., and continue to the last column.   It does not need to load the whole table and aggregate the element of rows into a new column.  Thus, it should  significantly speed up the operation.  Basically, spark load text/csv file as row-oriented data by default and if the operation is applied to each row, then the speed is very fast. If you want to  have column-wise operation, it is best to load the data as column-wise format.   Hope the idea is clear for you.

Comment: @XYZ That makes sense, thanks. I am taking modes over the columns here so column -oriented sounds like the way to go.